# SQL query taking long with NOT IN

Tags: t-sql

I am pretty sure the issue is with the datetime compare as when i remove it just works faster. can someone guide me on this. Also could be the NOT IN , as similiar query with IN clause works just fine, is there an altenative to writing this query to produce the same results.

```
with HT as (
            SELECT LEFT(E.patient_urno,1) as 'HTHospitalcode',RIGHT(E.patient_urno, LEN(E.patient_urno) - 1) 'HTRUno' , E.patient_urno 'HTpatient_urno',E.en_system_code 'HTen_system_code',CAST(start_dtm as date) 'HTstart_dtm' ,E.*
            FROM dbo.rpt_Encounter E JOIN [dbo].[rpt_V_DataSource_HTRK_Latest] DS ON DS.DatasourceID =  E.DatasourceID
                                         JOIN [dbo].[rpt_Patient] P ON E.PatientID = P.PatientID
            WHERE ISNULL(P.patient_urno,'') <> ''
                AND  (LEN(P.patient_urno) BETWEEN 6 AND 8)
                AND NOT ( P.patient_urno LIKE '9999999' OR P.patient_urno LIKE '99999999' )
                AND  (E.locations  LIKE 'Box Hill Cath Labs')
                AND (start_dtm) IS NOT NULL
                ), HIP as 


             (SELECT 
                          LEFT(DS1.Hospital_Code,1) 'HIPHospitalCode',P1.patient_urno 'HIPURno',LEFT(DS1.Hospital_Code,1)+E1.patient_urno 'HIPpatient_urno',E1.en_system_code 'HIPen_system_code',cast(start_dtm as date) 'HIPstart_dtm', cast(end_dtm as date)'HIPend_dtm' 
                      FROM 
                          [dbo].[rpt_Encounter] E1
                          JOIN [dbo].[rpt_V_DataSource_HOMR_IP_Latest] DS1 on DS1.[DataSourceID] = E1.[DataSourceID] 
                          LEFT JOIN [dbo].[rpt_Patient] P1 ON E1.PatientID = P1.PatientID 
                      WHERE 
                          ISNULL(P1.patient_urno, '') <> '' )


    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM HT where HTpatient_urno NOT IN (SELECT HIPpatient_urno FROM HIP WHERE HTstart_dtm BETWEEN HIPstart_dtm AND HIPend_dtm)
```

Comment: Performance tuning needs execution plan. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) As it is now, this question can't be answered

Answer (score 0):

This can be faster:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM HT WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM HIP WHERE HTstart_dtm BETWEEN HIPstart_dtm AND HIPend_dtm AND HTpatient_urno = HIPpatient_urno)
```

Also do you have indexes on he date and "urno" columns?

Comment: Please post questions as comment :) Stack Overflow works better in a `question->answer` fashion rather than in a forum-like thread.

Comment: Thanks i tried that and had no luck with it, the execution time is 1+ hour, FYR.. the HIP has 500K rows in it. So i may have not written this efficient enough

Comment: Thanks, made a negligible difference though , i still feel that its the datetime causing issues. i have he indexes created for urno and date